# scala: How do I find the last day of the month?

Tags: scala, date

I can find the implementation in various languages like C#, Dart etc on StackOverflow. How do we do it in Scala? I cannot see any 'Maximum value' function in LocalDate class.

Comment: Are you using joda time or java 8?

Comment: See the answer for Java: How to get the last date of a particular month with JodaTime? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711454/how-to-get-the-last-date-of-a-particular-month-with-jodatime