# How to get the last day of a month in a YearMonth object?

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm using the `YearMonth` object of `joda.time`, and want to get the last day of the month date in this object.

```
yearMonth.monthOfYear().getMaximumValue(); //return 12 as the maximum month value is =12
```

But what I want is the maximum day in that specific month? Eg 30 or 31 mostly. How can I get it?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624442/getting-last-day-of-the-month-in-given-string-date

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the last date of a particular month with JodaTime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711454/how-to-get-the-last-date-of-a-particular-month-with-jodatime)

Comment: @Jayram He is asking using jodatime not Calendar class. So its not duplicate

Comment: @Jayram this is a joda time question. NO dublicate!

Comment: @Jens I have a `YearMonth` object that does not have a `.dayOfMonth()` method. NO dublicate!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DateTime has this readymade feature.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
System.out.println(dt.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue());
```

But if you want it for YearMonth, then convert YearMonth to DateTime and do as above:

```
YearMonth ym = new YearMonth();
dt = ym.toDateTime(null);
System.out.println(dt.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get maximum day of the month in `Joda` you should use `LocalDate`

Eg:

```
LocalDate endOfMonth = LocalDate.fromDateFields(new 
                                         Date()).dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
System.out.println(endOfMonth);
```

Out put:

```
2014-10-31
```

From [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.Property.html#withMaximumValue%28%29)

```
This operation is useful for obtaining a LocalDate on the last day of the month, 
as month lengths vary.    
LocalDate lastDayOfMonth = dt.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
```

Comment: As written above, I do *only* have the `YearMonth` object. I do *not* have a `LocalDate`...

Answer (score 0):

Create a DateTime Object from your yearMonth:

```
DateTime datetime = new DateTime(yearMonth.get(DateTimeFieldType.year()), yearMonth.get(DateTimeFieldType.monthOfYear()),1,0,0);
System.out.println(datetime.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue());
```