# Joda Time Manipulation get 15th and last day of month

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

How can I get the 15th and last day of the month in Joda time in a loop?

This is the code looks like:

```
DateTime initDate = new DateTime(2015,1,31,0,0);

for(int i = 0; i > 4; i++){
  initDate = initDate.plusDays(15);

   System.out.println(initDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

I just want the result to be like this:

```
2015-2-15
2015-2-28
2015-3-15
2015-3-30
```

Comment: this surely will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711454/how-to-get-the-last-date-of-a-particular-month-with-jodatime

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){ 
            initDate = initDate.plusMonths(1);
            initDate = initDate.withDayOfMonth(15);
            System.out.println(initDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            System.out.println(initDate.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue().toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        }
```

Something like that?

Comment: Might not do what you think it does.  After all, the Maximum value of February is 29th, which is only correct about 25% of the time.

Comment: @EdwinBuck The answer is correct. The (elegant) method `withMaximumValue()` depends on context as you can easily verify yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The loop is fine but instead of adding days, you could add a month directly (have a look at http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html and
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Months.html) and than to get the last day of the month you can use

```
yourcurrentDate.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the last day of the month by adding a fixed number of days, because all months don't have the same length in days.

Instead, use your loop like so

```
for (each month) {
   set the month appropriately (set not add)
   get the 15th day of this month (set not add)
   print the 15th day
   set the next month
   set the 1st day of the "next" month
   subtract a day
   print the "last" day
}
```